# MQ Explorer Activity Viewer by mqsc commands

Tags: ibm-mq

WebSphere MQ Explorer has a feature called Activity Viewer that can monitor queue status, catching values it calls "Put", "Got" and "High depth" in defined intervals.

My question is: how to do the same by using *mqsc* command on server locally?
I know that you can request that "High Depth" with `dis qs(queue.name) curdepth` command, but I can't seem to find what will get me those "Put" and "Got" values Activity Viewer shows.

Answer (score 2):

WMQ Explorer uses a command called [Reset Queue Statistics](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/topic/com.ibm.mq.ref.adm.doc/q088300_.htm) (`MQCMD_RESET_Q_STATS`) that is not available as an MQSC command. It is provided only as a PCF command.  Part of the reason for this is that this command follows Quantum Physics rules, leading to the Heisenberg Uncertainty of Queue Stats problem.  Allow me to explain.

Issuing `MQCMD_RESET_Q_STATS` returns the stats since the last time the command was issued, resetting them at the same time.  I describe this as being like Quantum Physics because mere observation of the stats affects them.  Now imagine you are running a performance test and multiple people are interested in the outcome, and both are using WMQ Explorer to view the stats.  Each will see some value approximating 1/2 the activity.  Now try it with three people.  Four people.  You get the idea.  You can get some results back but if there's a chance someone else is doing the same thing you can never be certain of the quality of those results. (Hence the reference to Heisenberg.)

I believe that IBM does not make this an MQSC command because typically you would want some central monitor such as Tivloi to be the *only* thing using this command.  If they made it an MQSC command, everyone would want to use it.

Comment: Can you point me at some console tool that can issue PCF commands, please?

Comment: I do not know of any but the two places I'd look are IBM's SupportPacs page ( http://ibm.co/SupptPacs ) and Capitalware's index of all known WMQ tools ( http://www.capitalware.com/mqseries.html ).